# MariaDB, how to use a field name as a table name?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I'm trying to create a table that can reference another table where the table it is referencing is configured in one of the records:

The rules table 'tblRules':

```
    biRuleID, BIGINT, Unsigned, Primary Key
    biTableID, BIGINT, Unsigned, Link to record in 'other' table
    vcDescription, VARCHAR[64], Description of rule
    vcTableName, VARCHAR[64], The name of the table containing the rule details.
```

A test table, 'tblTest':

```
    biTestID, BIGINT, Unsigned, Primary Key
    vcTest, VARCHAR[64], A test string
```

To test, tblRules contains a single record:

```
    1, 1, Testing rule, tblTest
```

And tblTest contains:

```
    1, Hello World
```

Now I want to pull in the data:

```
    SELECT
      * 
    FROM 
      tblRules t1 
    LEFT JOIN 
      t1.vcTableName t2 
    ON 
      t1.biTableID=t2.biTestID 
    WHERE 
      t1.biRuleID=1;
```

However when I try to execute the query it seems to be taking t1.vcTableName as the name of the table not the content of what vcTableName contains, is there a way to sort this out?

Comment: I'm not a MariaDB user, but generally this thing (using the values from a column in the query itself) isn't possible in SQL (and may in fact be against the SQL standards). You need to get meta somehow, with either a language on top of SQL, or by using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE to  dynamically generate and execute the SQL statement.

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor design

Comment: I am aiming for complete flexibility and scalability

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use dynamic sql to achieve it, though I think you have to do smth with your DB design as that's not too effective

```
set @qry = (
    SELECT
      concat('SELECT * FROM tblRules t1 LEFT JOIN ', t1.vcTableName, ' t2 ON t1.biTableID = t2.biTestID WHERE t1.biRuleID=1') 
    FROM 
      tblRules t1 
    WHERE 
      t1.biRuleID=1
);
PREPARE qry FROM @qry;
EXECUTE qry;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE qry;
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this out tonight and post back.